# Hash Table of Vectors of Person Objects c

Tags: c++, object, hash, vector, hashtable

I've been working on a very in depth project for one of my classes. It supposed to read in Person objects and put them into a hash table. I'm still trying to get my head around the concept of a hash table so any help would be appreciated. 
It will be hashing based on last name and since some people may have the same last name, I was going to make each bucket a vector of Person objects. I'm trying to test the class by adding a person to the hash function and then returning it. My code compiles successfully but I get a thread error in the put function on this line:  table[index].push_back(p);

Could anyone please help me figure out what is going wrong? Thank you!

```
int main()
{
    HashTable ht(10);
    ht.put(p1, p1->lName);
    ht.getName("Booras");
}


HashTable:
#include "Person.h"
#include <vector>

class HashTable: public DataStructures
{
private:
    vector<vector<Person>> table;
public:
    HashTable(int tableSize);
    ~HashTable();
    int tableSize;
    void getName(string str); //prints out friends with matching name
    void put(Person p, string str);
    void remove(Person *p, string str);
    int hash(string str);

};
HashTable::HashTable(int tableSize)
{
    vector< vector<Person> > table(tableSize, vector<Person>(tableSize));
    for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
        table.push_back(vector<Person>()); // Add an empty row
    }
}

HashTable::~HashTable()
{

}

//Find a person with the given last name
void HashTable::getName(string key)
{
    int index = hash(key);
    for(int i=0; i<table[index].size(); i++)
    {
        if(table[index][i].lName.compare(key) == 0)
            std::cout << "Bucket: " << index << "Bin: " << i;
            table[index][i].print();
    }
    //create exception for person not found
}

void HashTable::put(Person p, string str)
{
    int index = hash(str);
    table[index].push_back(p);
}

void HashTable::remove(Person *p, string str)
{
    int index = hash(str);
    int i=0;
    while(&table[index][i] != p && i<table[index].size())
        i++;
    for(int j=i; j<table[index].size()-1; j++)
        table[index][j] = table[index][j+1];
    table[index].pop_back();
}

int HashTable::hash(string str)
{
    int hashValue = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
        hashValue = hashValue + int(str[i]);
    }
    hashValue %= tableSize;
    if(hashValue<0) hashValue += tableSize;
    return hashValue;
}
```

Main:

```
int main() {
    Person *p1 = new Person("Kristy", "Booras", "Reston", "03/15");
    HashTable ht(10);
    ht.put(*p1, p1->lName);
    ht.get("Booras");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of `HashTable::hash` member function ?

Comment: BTW: How does your `main()` compile? Is `p1` a pointer (then you shouldn't be able to call `put` like this) or a `Person` object (then `p1->lName` shouldn't work unless you surprisingly overload that operator)?

Comment: Just posted the hash function and a bit of my main function that does the hash table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show us the `HashTable::hash(string)` member function, but I'd assume that your problems originate in the `HashTable`constructor: You don't initialize the `tableSize` member variable, which you'll need to calculate a valid hashed index.

While looking at the constructor:

```
HashTable::HashTable(int tableSize)
{
    vector< vector<Person> > table(tableSize, vector<Person>(tableSize));
```

This has initialized `table` to have `tableSize` non-empty elements, for a total of `tableSize * tableSize`default-constructed `Person` objects.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
        table.push_back(vector<Person>()); // Add an empty row
    }
}
```

Now you have added more rows, so that `table.size() == 2*tableSize`, with the first half of entries non-empty (as explained above) and the second half holding empty vectors.

That is probably not what you intended.

And in all of that you haven't initialized the member `tableSize`. It easily gets confusing, if you use local variables or argument names that hide member names.

Comment: So how would I build my constructor to create a hash table of tableSize empty vectors of Person objects?

Comment: `HashTable::HashTable(int tableSize) : table(tableSize), tableSize(tableSize) {}` would be a complete constructor that behaves as you want.

Comment: Or to eliminate the naming confusion: `HashTable::HashTable(int bucketCount) : table(bucketCount), tableSize(bucketCount) {}`